# do i (Nepali National) need visa to transit Miami airport to travel another country?

Tags: visas, american-airlines, delta-air-lines

i (Nepali National) have been getting connecting flight at Miami Airport to travel Cayman Islands. do i need to obtain transit visa or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely! The US has **no** exit immigration control (domestic and international flights use the same gates), so everyone Needs to clear immigration and customs and then departures security.

This means you'll Need a C-1 (Transit) visa.